# TypeScript Compiler Errors on String

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have this strange problem in my VS 2015 project where I'm getting 47,114 compiler errors in Typescript but the program works anyway, and generates the JS file correctly.

> *Error    TS2339  Property 'fromCharCode' does not exist on type 'StringConstructor'. MyProject   c:...\Scripts\Autocode.ts  70  Active
>   Error TS2339  Property 'length' does not exist on type
>   'String'. MyProject   c:...\Scripts\Autocode.ts  70  Active
>   Error TS2339  Property 'substr' does not exist on type
>   'String'. MyProject   c:...\Scripts\Autocode.ts  70  Active
>   Error TS2339  Property 'floor' does not exist on type
>   ''.   MyProject   c:...\Scripts\Autocode.ts  70  Active
>   Error TS2339  Property 'fromCharCode' does not exist on type
>   'StringConstructor'.  MyProject   c:...\Scripts\Autocode.ts  70  Active
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error TS2304  Cannot find name 'number'.  MyProject   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.d.ts   5925    Active
>   Error TS1005  ';' expected.   MyProject   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.d.ts   5925    Active
>   Error TS1109  Expression expected.    MyProject   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.d.ts   5925    Active*

47,000 of these types of errors but the program runs well.

How can I correct these errors?

Comment: Please add code snippet;

Comment: I don't think a code snippet would help.  It's basically stuff like mystring.length type code.

Comment: May be you should change name of your class `StringConstructor`, because plenty of methods of string type are missing.

Comment: Also please make habit to add code snippet, its no sense how you are getting error

Answer (score 1):

You might not have included es2015 into your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "lib": ["es2015"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install VS 2015 Update 3, then install `TypeScript 2.0.3 for Visual Studio 2015` extension.